# How is this Conditional Joint Probability derived?

Tags: probability

This is in the context of data augmentation for a probit model. In the literature I'm studying the following is given:

$p(y, z \mid \beta)=p(y \mid z, \beta) p(z \mid \beta)$

It looks like they use the law to total probability, only they do so without using an integral or summation, which confuses me.

Can somebody help me by showing that this holds?

The probit model is given by:

$Y_i= \begin{cases}1 & \text { if } z_i=x_i^{\prime} \beta+\varepsilon_i>0 \\ 0 & \text { if } z_i=x_i^{\prime} \beta+\varepsilon_i \leq 0\end{cases}$

Comment: $p(y, z \mid \beta)=p(y \mid z, \beta) p(z \mid \beta)$ is an application of conditional probability, just $p(y, z)=p(y \mid z) p(z )$ all conditioned on $\beta$

Comment: Thank you! shame that I did not found out myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check this equality straightforwardly.
I will use $\mathbb{P}$ to denote probability.

From the one side by the definition of the conditional probability,
$$\mathbb{P}(y,z |\beta)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(y,z,\beta)}{\mathbb{P}(\beta)}$$
From the other side, using the definition of the conditional probability, we can simplify the right hand side as follows :
$$\mathbb{P}(y|z,\beta)\cdot\mathbb{P}(z|\beta)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(y,z,\beta)}{\mathbb{P}(z,\beta)}\cdot\frac{\mathbb{P}(z,\beta)}{\mathbb{P}(\beta)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(y,z,\beta)}{\mathbb{P}(\beta)}$$

As the right hand side and the left hand side are equal to the same expression, it follows that
$$\mathbb{P}(y,z |\beta)=\mathbb{P}(y|z,\beta)\cdot\mathbb{P}(z|\beta)$$